# Configuring the NEo4j ETL Tool

Tags: neo4j, etl, graph-databases

My project includes importing data from a relational database(mySql) to neo4j.To do this I chose to use the Neo4j ETL Tool.The first database that i imported worked perfectly fine.However the second database did not work so well.I find 3 blocks that I wanted to change.

One was that the direction of the relationship seemed arbitrary to me.The tool randomly assigned the relationships.I am not really sure if it was random.Please correct me if i am wrong.

The second was that the records in the tables of the relational database that have have the same records were considered as one relationship in the graph.Let me explain more on this point.I have a "complaints" table.The table has two foreign key relationships.
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`customer_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `Department` (`Department_id`)
In the graph the "COMPLAINTS" relationship is created between the "Customer" and "Department" nodes.two of my records in the Complaints table have the same customer_id and Department_id.Both these records have been denoted as a single relationship between Customer_id 4 and Department_id 5.I want it to be shown as two separate relationships.How do i change this.

Third is that a few columns of a particular table are not represented as properties in the graph.the Category_id column of "Categories" table does not show as a property on the Catgory nodes in the graph.How do i rectify this.

Is there any way to configure the neo4j ETL Tool so that i can customize it?